# Python: string to int or zero on error, without try/except

Tags: python

In the spirit of short code... I have a list of either numbers or empty strings and I want to `map(int, mylist)` without it failing.

```
mylist = "123//456".split("/") #['123', '', '456']
myints = <something to quickly convert the list>
```

**EDIT** *I need to keep the same number of tokens*. I.e. `myints = [123, 0, 456]`.

I was thinking of something along the lines of `map(lambda x: int(x) or 0, mylist)`, but of course this still throws a `ValueError`. Any ideas?

---

**Another EDIT**

Some results (timing `for xrange(1000000)`)...

- *2.03s* `l = map(lambda x: x.isdigit() and int(x) or 0, mylist)`
- *1.37s* `l = [x.isdigit() and int(x) or 0 for x in mylist]`
- *1.99s* `l = map(lambda x: int(x) if x.isdigit() else 0, mylist)`
- *1.35s* `l = [int(x) if x.isdigit() else 0 for x in mylist]`
- *1.24s* `l = [int(x or 0) for x in mylist]`
- *1.45s* `l = [int(e) if e.strip() else 0 for e in mylist]`
- *4.44s* `the big chunk of code with try/except` ergo bigger is slower :) ok, not always

Just included these for their time as they don't produce the desired output...

- *3.71s* `l = map(int, re.findall('[0-9]+', "123//456"))` ('course regex is slow. time&place)
- *1.47s* `l = map(int, filter(None, mylist))`
- *1.15s* `[int(x) for x in mylist if x]` (nice time!)

**I should mention `re.compile` shaves 3.71s down to 2.11s.*

`Python 2.7.3, Xeon E5-1607`

**`myints = [int(x or 0) for x in mylist]`** is not only the fastest with the correct result but also VERY short at 29 characters.

Thanks all for your input! Not so much the downvoters :P

Comment: @Pyson If only I could relax arbitrary restrictions, coding in general would be much simpler :)  In this case I actually need to know which position the integer came from as the string may be `"123/456/789"`.

Comment: There are other and more robust ways to do that.

Comment: @Pyson Feel free to share them/add an answer :) I'm interested to know!

Comment: @Pyson If "Silly restriction" is referring to try/except and not same-number-of-tokens, my timing results seem to suggest otherwise.

Comment: Perhaps you wouldn't have received the downvote had you put the valuable timing results in an answer rather than in the question, but I'm only guessing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short, though not as robust as other answers -- `x` must be an empty string or a number:

```
[int(x or 0) for x in mylist]
```

Comment: very nice. without `isdigit()` overhead too

Answer (score 3):

Short isn't always the best, but this is pretty short:

```
>>> [int(e) if e.strip() else 0 for e in "123//456".split("/")]
[123, 0, 456]
```

Also:

```
>>> map(int, (e if e.isdigit() else '0' for e in "123//456".split("/")))
```

Comment: Upvoting in particular for the second form, which shows a different use of `map` than the rest of the answers. The first form depends on the OP's statement that the input will only be digit strings or empty strings - it's not wrong as long as that constraint holds, but it's more vulnerable to bad input like "1/a/2" than the forms that use `isdigit`. How much that matters depends on how certain the OP is of the input format.

Answer (score 2):

```
myints = map(lambda x: int(x) if x.isdigit() else 0, "123//456".split("/")) # returns [123, 0, 456]
```

As you wanted, **it keeps the same numbers of tokens, and replaces non-digit strings with zeroes**.

**Edit:** You can also do it via comprehensions:

```
myints = [int(x) if x.isdigit() else 0 for x in "123//456".split("/")]
```

Comment: Actually I quite liked your first idea, using the `[... for ...]` syntax: `[x.isdigit() and int(x) or 0 for x in mylist]`.

Comment: @jozxyqk well, I've just shown you how you can do it via `map` function as it was your original idea, but yes, you can use comprehensions also.

Answer (score 2):

This looks to me like a situation where a `for` loop would be more readable than a list comprehension. But if you really want to do it in as little code as possible, try this:

```
myints = [int(x) if x.isdigit() else 0 for x in mylist]
```

Obviously you could use any value you liked in place of 0 for non-digit strings, which will include empty strings.

The `for` loop form would be something like this:

```
myints = []
for x in mylist:
    try:
        intx = int(x)
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        intx = 0
    finally:
        myints.append(intx)
```

That form has the advantage of working on any input that `int` can handle, with negative numbers leaping to mind - `'-7'.isidigit()` will return `False`, so any of the `int(x) if x.isdigit() else 0` solutions will turn `'123//-7'` into `[123, 0, 0]` rather than `[123, 0, -7]`. Your problem statement doesn't address negative integers so I'm not sure what you need there.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [list comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/):

```
my_ints = [int(x) for x in my_str.split('/') if x]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `regex`:

```
>>> import re
>>> map(int, re.findall('[0-9]+', "123//456////1231231"))
[123, 456, 1231231]
```

If string is huge then you can use `re.finditer` and a list comprehension:

```
>>> [int(m.group()) for m in re.finditer('[0-9]+', "123//456////1231231")]
[123, 456, 1231231]
```

For your [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19722370/revisions), you can use [`str.isdigit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) and a [ternary expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
>>> mylist = "123//456"
>>> [int(x) if x.isdigit() else 0 for x in mylist.split('/')]
[123, 0, 456]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not split at the `'//'`?

```
print map(int, "123//456".split('//'))
```

If this isn't an option, then you can do:

```
print map(int, filter(None, mylist))
```

Or if you want to keep the same length:

```
print map(lambda x: int(x) if x.isdigit() else 0, mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is one way that works, but there is the extra call to `.isdigit()`, which doesn't seem like it should be necessary.

```
mylist = "123//456".split("/") #['123', '', '456']
myints = map(lambda x: x.isdigit() and int(x) or 0, mylist)

[123, 0, 456]
```

Comment: Using `isdigit` is good, but using `and` and `or` to simulate a ternary operator is both ugly and (as of Python 2.5) unnecessary: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper can you show the preferred way to write an inline if/then/else?

Comment: `int(x) if x.isdigit() else 0` in place of `x.isdigit() and int(x) or 0`.